# table mapping unable error in SQlite connection in windows application

Tags: c#, sqlite, uwp

When i connect my application with SQLite database. The following exception throw.

```
 An exception of type 'SQLite.SQLiteException' occurred in
 Scrap_Book.Windows.exe but was not handled in user code

 Additional information: no such table: CONTENT
```

I created the table with the help of SqLite manager an adon of mozila firefox.
Please help me how I can solve this problem.

```
          var dbpath =    Path.Combine(Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path, "MYSCRAPBOOK.sqlite");
        using (var db = new SQLite.SQLiteConnection(dbpath))

            db.Insert(new CONTENT()
            {
                STICKERS=snodesticker
            });


             db.Commit();
            db.Dispose();
            db.Close();
            var line = new MessageDialog("Records Inserted");
            await line.ShowAsync();
```

Comment: You could start by accepting, that the error message is in fact correct.

Answer (score 0):

According to message from your exception you haven't created `CONTENT` table.

So, I guess you need to create table before inserting data.

```
public static string DB_NAME = "ContactsManager.sqlite";
public static string DB_PATH = Path.Combine(Path.Combine(ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path, DB_NAME));//DataBase Name 

private async Task<bool> CheckFileExistsAsync(string fileName)
{
    try
    {
        var store = await Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFileAsync(fileName);
        return true;
    }
    catch
    {
    }
    return false;
}

if (!(await CheckFileExistsAsync(DB_NAME)))
{
    using (var db = new SQLiteConnection(DB_PATH))
    {
        db.CreateTable<CONTENT>();
    }
}
```